# Why UIButton Automatically change imageView.hidden = false

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

This is part of my code, in which I add a subview to an `UIButton`.

```
self.imageView?.hidden = true
        guard self.subviews.contains(frequencyView) else {
            print("show frequency view\(self.imageView?.hidden)")
            self.addSubview(frequencyView)
            print("show frequency view\(self.imageView?.hidden)")
            self.imageView?.hidden = true
            print("show frequency view\(self.imageView?.hidden)")
            return
        }
```

However I when I set the button's imageView.hidden = true before I addSubview. It'll automatically change the hidden state to false.

```
show frequency viewOptional(true)
show frequency viewOptional(false)
show frequency viewOptional(true)
```

Is there any method that can prevent it from happening? or do I have to change it back to true after that.